# Remove dates from array other than between FROM DATE and TO DATE

Tags: php, date

I have an array in php like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
             [date] => 21/07/2014 
             [total_booking] => 1 
           ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
             [date] => 1/08/2014 
             [total_booking] => 1 
           ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
             [date] => 2/09/2014 
             [total_booking] => 2 
           )
)
```

if i get value `$_POST['from_date']` and `$_POST['to_date']` all array other than between this `from_date,to_date` should be removed.

**Edit   my code**

```
foreach ($newarray as $newarray){
if ($newarray[Date] < $to_date && $from_date > $newarray[Date])
{
 // i want to remove this row from array
}

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? You could do an array filter, in which you check for `strtotime` on the date.

Comment: @DaveChen can you expalin.. i am new in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using array_filter:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array(
        'date' => '21/07/2014',
        'total_booking' => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '1/08/2014',
        'total_booking' => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'date' => '2/09/2014',
        'total_booking' => '2'
    )
);

$from_date = strtotime('01-08-2014'); //$_POST['from_date']
$to_date = strtotime('21-08-2014'); //$_POST['to_date']

$data = array_filter($data, function($array) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
    $epoch = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $array['date']));
    return $epoch >= $from_date && $epoch <= $to_date;
});

$data = array_values($data);

print_r($data);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/e10e01301480cf):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 1/08/2014
            [total_booking] => 1
        )

)
```

Only one element is outputted because only `1/08/2014` is between `1/08/2014` and `21/08/2014`.

For earlier PHP versions:

```
function filter($array) {
    $from_date = strtotime('01-08-2014'); //$_POST['from_date']
    $to_date = strtotime('21-08-2014'); //$_POST['to_date']

    $epoch = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $array['date']));
    return $epoch >= $from_date && $epoch <= $to_date;
}

$data = array_filter($data, 'filter');
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['from_date']) && isset($_POST['to_date'])){

               $from_date = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['from_date'])); 
               $to_date = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['to_date'])); 
               $finalarray = array_filter($finalarray, function($array) {
               $epoch = str_replace('/', '-', strtotime($array['date'])); 
              return $epoch >= $from_date && $epoch <= $to_date; 
               });
              print_r($finalarray);
              
            }`  this is the code i have done but i am getting the same array

Comment: What values for `$_POST` are being submitted? Is it a date picker? In that case it might be in another format, and you should just have `$to_date = strtotime($_POST['to_date'])` and `$from_date = strtotime($_POST['from_date'])`.

Comment: Yea datepcker.  this is the ` dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'`

Comment: Add a `print_r($_POST)` and comment the results. It should remove all values that are not in between your declared interval.

Comment: `Array ([to_date] => 01-07-2014 [from_date] => 03-07-2014 )`  this is the output

Comment: The issue is that you have `to_date` and `from_date` flipped around. The first date, `from_date` is 2 days after `to_date`. You should change the naming within your HTML form.

Comment: Some typing mistake, it actually is 
`Array ([to_date] => 18-07-2014 [from_date] => 01-07-2014 )`

Comment: again i am nott geting

Comment: @NishamMahsin I made a mistake in my code. Please copy it again and replace `$to_date` and `$from_date` with the proper `$_POST`s.

Comment: sir again same problem ..same array

Comment: `$from_date = strtotime('01-07-2014'); $to_date = strtotime('18-07-2014');` returns an empty array which is expected. What values are you testing with? Also make sure you replace the entire code, the above code was changed an hour ago.

Comment: thanks now i am getting...but array is like this `Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 17/06/2014
            [total_booking] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 18/06/2014
            [total_booking] => 2
        )

)`   .  how to change the array index to 0,1 ..

Comment: @NishamMahsin You can reindex the array with `$data = array_values($data);`. I have added it in the code above to show where it fits.

Comment: Its working fine on local but when i place it in server it gives
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION  (array filter).
PHP version in server is 5.2.17. What to doo?

Comment: @NishamMahsin Either upgrade (highly recommended), or separate function (as shown above).